# How do I display a counter function in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I know that in c++ you do int counter and when it does something I want its gonna do c++ and then `cout<< counter` to show the counter but now I want to do a GUI app which will have 20 buttons and when a button is pressed to do the counter++ and print the counter. I have done it but how do I do it to show the counter in a label?

**code**

```
        #include "form.h"
        #include "ui_form.h"
        #include <QString>
        #include <QLabel>

        Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
            QWidget(parent),
            ui(new Ui::Form)
        {
            QString::number();
            QString s = QString::number();
            ui->setupUi(this);

        }

        Form::~Form()
        {
            delete ui;
        }

        void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
        {

            counter++;

            ui->label->setText(QString::number(counter));
        }
```

**header**:

```
                           #ifndef FORM_H
        #define FORM_H

        #include <QWidget>
        #include <QString>

        namespace Ui {
        class Form;
        }

        class Form : public QWidget
        {
            Q_OBJECT

        public:
            explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
            ~Form();

        private slots:
            void on_pushButton_clicked();
            int counter=0;

        private:
            Ui::Form *ui;
        };

        #endif // FORM_H
```

errors I get:

1)

> no matching function for call to 'QString::number()'
>        QString::number();

Comment: you can use the setText(...) method of your label to set it after each button click...

Comment: @retinotop setText(counter)?

Comment: you need to convert your counter to an qstring... cause i think it is an int value...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211771/how-to-convert-int-to-qstring

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider done

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider so yea what should I do now?

Comment: @retinotop i have added QString::number();
    int counter;
    QString s = QString::number(); but doesnt work

Comment: Can u show also your header? Or better, the label is shown in the gui?!

Comment: @retinotop yea the label is shown in the gui, I have just updated it with the header

Comment: by the way you are using it like: label->setText(QString::number(counter));    and the label can show some text?

Comment: @retinotop it doesnt run shows some errors.

Comment: ok, can you update your code, and add your errors?

Comment: @retinotop want to dd u on skype cause there are alot fo errors so I can share screen?

Comment: @xPosed no we can't share on skype... put your code and the first errors... You need allways take care on the first errors.. mostly all other errors will disappear after fixing the first errors.

Comment: @retinotop I haev just edited the code including the issues.

Comment: yes first of all you need to include QString --> #include <QString>   ... are you really sure you updated your code?

Comment: @retinotop new error message: no matching function for call to 'QString::number()'
     QString s = QString::number();
                                 ^

Comment: You need to add your src in the cpp and in the header... you just updated the error messages...

Comment: @retinotop how? help plz

Comment: You need to edit your post on top and change the source code.

Comment: @retinotop updated.

Comment: `counter` needs to be a member of `Form`.  As it is, its declaration in the constructor is not visible in the slot definition.

Comment: @aschepler how? should I create a label and call it counter? and how am I gonna increase the number?

Comment: remove the QString number things in your constructor...

Comment: I say next time post the line number of the error including the full text of the error message and the code around the error. The code for the question now only needs the constructor and all the text of the question is not that useful. Since it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @xPosed You have it right now that `int counter=0;` is in the class definition.

Comment: made it work guys thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    counter = 0;
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    counter++;
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(counter));
}
```

Initialize your member in the constructor not in the header. And put the definition of your counter member to the private section not to the private slot section.